# Tengo un Error 53 sql server y no encuentra instancia

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema con el SQL Server 2017 ,ya que al conectarme y autentificarlo con Windows me aparece un **error 53**.

El cual dice que no se encontró la ruta especifica de la instancia para conectarse. Abrí el SQL Server Configuration Manager pero no me aparece ninguna instancia para habilitarla, y quise iniciar el servicio de SQL Server desde el administrador de tareas y aparece que no está instalado y no se puede iniciar. ¿Cómo resuelvo este problema?

Ya que lo desinstalé y lo volví a instalar, el SQL Server y no me deja porque no encuentra ninguna instancia.

**INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:**

> Se ha producido un error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia al establecer una conexión con SQL Server. El servidor no se encontró o no estaba accesible. Verifique que el nombre de la instancia sea correcto y que SQL Server esté configurado para permitir conexiones remotas. (proveedor: Proveedor de canalizaciones con nombre, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Comment: edita y agrega el codigo del error

Comment: ya puse el error que me aparece @Gilberto

Comment: Entonces el respuesta es clara. No encuentra ninguna instancia porque no la hay. Tu instalación de SQL no está correcta y más porque comentas que ni siquiera la puedes ver en la configuración. Trata de correr nuevamente el ejecutable de SQL y hay una opción para crear una nueva instancia. Úsala y configurala con autenticación SQL.

Comment: el problema es que cuando la corro nuevamente no me aparece la opcion de crear una nueva instancia o algo referente a ella, me aparece directamente como si el sql ubicara el archivo raiz de la instancia que tenia anteriormente ,sin embargo esa carpeta no existe ,no tengo ninguna instancia anterior  @ Jonsin

Comment: Si creas una Instancia diferente a la (local), entonces debes llamar a la instancia de esta manera: NombreDelPC\Instancia.